# Sorting NSMutableArray does not change object order

Tags: objective-c

Here is the code I use to sort items in an NSMutableArray. The code works without errors but after applying the filter, the order doesn't change. Am I doing something wrong?

```
NSArray *filtered = [posts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    Post *post1 = (Post *)obj1;
    Post *post2 = (Post *)obj2;

    int p1 = post1.firstPhotoVoters.count + post1.firstPhotoVoters.count;
    int p2 = post2.firstPhotoVoters.count + post2.firstPhotoVoters.count;

    if (p1 < p2) return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    if (p1 > p2) return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: "the order doesn't change" -  are you checking order of `posts` or `filtered`?

Comment: The `NSComparisonResult` casts are completely unneccessary. Also, your `p1` and `p2` variables are strange, since they are taking only the double of the count (and they should be `NSUInteger`). Sorting by double value is equivalent to sorting just by value.

Comment: Are you checking the order of `filtered` or `posts`?  Is the `NSOrderedSame` return always reached when the block is executed?

Comment: @CodaFi Right, if the `firstPhotoVoters` are `nil` or empty, the order won't change.

Comment: @Sulthan the cast is necessary for LLVM < 5.0 due to the odd quasi-type inference of blocks.

Comment: @Sulthan I didn't notice I was using firstPhotoVoters property twice, a silly copy paste error. If you post your comment as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int p1 = post1.firstPhotoVoters.count + post1.firstPhotoVoters.count;
int p2 = post2.firstPhotoVoters.count + post2.firstPhotoVoters.count;
```

You are using the same property twice. There should be probably a different property as one of the operands.

Answer (score 1):

You could put breakpoints on `return NSOrderedAscending` and `return NSOrderedDescending`, log `firstPhotoVoters.count` for both objects to see if something unexpected is happening. The code is fine apart from the fact that you could use

```
int p1 = post1.firstPhotoVoters.count;
int p2 = post2.firstPhotoVoters.count;
```

instead of

```
int p1 = post1.firstPhotoVoters.count + post1.firstPhotoVoters.count;
int p2 = post2.firstPhotoVoters.count + post2.firstPhotoVoters.count;
```

and nothing would change, its a waste of cycles.

Comment: When you say the order doesn't change, you do mean the order of filtered compared to posts?

Comment: Right side of the sum operator should be secondPhotoVoters.count. Thanks for the help.